# If an aircraft does not have an FDR, must one be installed to comply with Flight Data Monitoring requirements in EASA countries?

Tags: flight-data-recorder, easa, flight-data-monitoring

Flight Data Monitoring (FDM), which analyzes FDR data to accomplish things like ensuring that pilots are following SOP's, is a requirement for EASA's Third Country Operators (TCO) certification, however certain (older) aircraft [do not seem to require an FDR](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29496/69).

Does this effectively change the requirement so that an FDR must be installed in an aircraft in order to accomplish FDM or is there an exception for FDM as well?  I have been unable to find anything specifically addressing this.

Comment: Related documents: [Annex III To ED Decision 2020-12-017R, ORO.AOC.130](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/Annex%20to%20ED%20Decision%202012-017-R.pdf) and [EU CAA CAP739 Flight Data Monitoring](http://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/CAP739.pdf)

Comment: Page 185 of the CAP739 document has some interesting tables that may help to clear this up.

Comment: @RonBeyer Interesting reading, but I don't see anything in either document which covers what I asked.

Comment: Yeah its not a straight answer, probably just a few pieces to a complicated puzzle of EASA regulations. I did find some references that QAR's may be used instead of FDR's, I'm not sure though if a QAR would be an easier/cheaper install than an FDR/CVR. It is also possible that nobody is using an older aircraft over the 27,000kg requirement where an FDM would be required, I guess the only way to know would be to look at all the equipment of operators not on the EU ban list...

Comment: @RonBeyer Well, from what I understand, a QAR works in conjunction with an FDR and simply records data from it to an easily accessible / replaceable media. At any rate, I agree that it's complicated, which is what led me to ask this question in the first place, lol.

Answer (score 1):

For 20 PAX and more, it becomes mandatory.

https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/le-piper-malibu-un-avion-delicat-22-01-2019-2287804_26.php

> Les boîtes noires sont obligatoires sur les appareils de transport public d'au moins vingt sièges.

Comment: My French is rusty, but the context of the article seems to be talking about a CVR, while the question is specifically asking about an FDR. Either way, the primary source of a regulation carries a lot more weight than what some reporter thinks he understood. (Not that the press ***ever*** gets their reporting wrong about aviation facts, right?)

Comment: It says the black boxes( in plural) become mandatory for 20 pax and more. Nevertheless I agree it is not strictly an aviation document.